# EditText modo Hex en Android

Tags: android, edittext

necesito introducir solo caracteres hexadecimales a un editText en Android, pero estos caracteres deben de ingresarse por pares, después de cada par automáticamente se debe de insertar un espacio y luego el siguiente par y así sucesivamente, alguien me podria decirme como hacerlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ingresar los caracteres hex estoy usando este código:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
 KeyEvent event) {
 if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
  || event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
  && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
  Log.d("", tv.getText().toString());
  return true;
  }
 return false;
 }
});
```

y el layout xml esta asi:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:digits="0123456789ABCDEF"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters" />
```

Comment: que solo acepte caracteres hexadecimales o convertir lo que escribes en hexadecimal?

Comment: Que solo acepte caracteres hexadecimales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma de permitir que tu `EditText` únicamente acepte caracteres hexadecimales es mediante las propiedades:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"

    android:digits="0123456789ABCDEF"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"/>
```

Esto configuraría tu `EditText` a únicamente recibir los caracteres configurados en `android:digits`.

Pero lo que deseas es que además agregue un espacio cada dos caracteres, para realizar esto puedes definir un [InputFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter), donde evaluara si el carácter es alfanumérico y mediante un `REGEX` si esta comprendido en los caracteres `"0123456789ABCDEF"`, al detectar que has escrito 2 caracteres permitidos agregará un espacio para los siguientes :

```
  private int counterForSpace = 0;
...
...

    InputFilter inputFilterText = new InputFilter() {

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

            Pattern patern = Pattern.compile("^\\p{XDigit}+$");

            //Stringbuilder para almacenar caracteres
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {

                if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(source.charAt(i)) && !Character.isSpaceChar(source.charAt(i))                            ) {
                    //Caracter no permitido, no escribe caracter;
                    return "";
                }

                //Solo permite caracteres "0123456789ABCDEF";
                Matcher matcher = patern.matcher(String.valueOf(source.charAt(i)));
                if (!matcher.matches()) {
                    return "";
                }

                //Agrega caracter
                sb.append(source.charAt(i));

                counterForSpace++;
                if(counterForSpace>1){
                    //Reinicia contador
                    counterForSpace = 0;
                    //Agrega espacio
                    sb.append(" ");
                }

            }
            //Agrega texto y convierte a mayusculas
            return  sb.toString().toUpperCase();
        }
    };

    myTextField.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { inputFilterText });
    myTextField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

De esta forma obtendrías el comportamiento deseado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]