# Como cambiar una propiedad de EditText por código

Tags: android

En mi aplicación estoy usando un solo `EditText` para ingresar:
caracteres de texto libre y caracteres Hexadecimales, de acuerdo a ciertas condiciones, para ello he colocado este atributo en el archivo layout xml:

```
android:digits="0123456789ABCDEF"
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
```

Con esto el edittext solo me esta aceptando caracteres Hexadecimales pero yo necesito manipular por código para que este EditText pueda aceptar caracteres hexadecimales o texto libre, me refiero tanto a "ABCDEFGHIJ...." asi como ""#$12345$%&&%(/&)...",  es decir a los caracteres de uso común para que incluyen letras, números y caracteres especiales.

> Para realizar el cambio de modo "default" y modo "Hexadecimal" puedes usar un botón el cual cambien el valor de una variable que determine el modo a operar, y mediante un switch en el InputFilter defines que realizar.

Jorgesys, tu codigo lo he probado en el emulador del Android SDK y funciona OK, tambien lo he probado en un smartphone LG y funciona, pero lo he probado en dos modelos diferentes de Samsung y tengo dos problemas:

1.- Cuando está en modo HEX si por accidente se presiona una tecla diferente a un carácter hexadecimal el teclado queda bloqueado y ya no acepta ningun caracter, se tiene que borrar todo con la teclado de retroceso para que pueda volver a aceptar el caracter presionado

2.- Cuando escribo "A" el texto muestra como "A" ahora cuando escribo "B" así que el texto debe ser "AB" pero me da "AAB" esto parece muy extraño!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tal vez te sirva esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5800511/3239070)

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes realizar mediante un [InputFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter), similar a esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/211240/95), pero en este caso únicamente valida espacios y convierte a mayúsculas el texto ingresado:

```
    EditText myTextField = findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

    InputFilter inputFilterText = new InputFilter() {

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                //valida espacios
                if (Character.isSpaceChar(source.charAt(i))) {                        
                    return "";
                }

                sb.append(source.charAt(i));

            }

            return  sb.toString().toUpperCase();
        }
    };

    myTextField.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { inputFilterText });
    myTextField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Para realizar el cambio de modo "default" y modo "Hexadecimal" puedes usar un botón el cual cambien el valor de una variable que determine el modo a operar, y mediante un `switch` en el `InputFilter` defines que realizar.

Este sería un ejemplo:

```
private EditText myEditText;
private static final int MODO_DEFAULT = 0;
private static final int MODO_HEXADECIMAL = 1;
private static int modo_activo = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Activa modo DEFAULT
            if(modo_activo == 0){
                modo_activo = 1;
                myEditText.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"MODO HEXADECIMAL",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                modo_activo = 0;
                myEditText.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"MODO DEFAULT",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    //Obtiene referencia de EditText
    myEditText = findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

    InputFilter inputFilterText = new InputFilter() {

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

            //REGEX que permite únicamente alfanmericos
            Pattern patern = Pattern.compile("^\\p{XDigit}+$");

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {

                switch(modo_activo) {
                    case MODO_DEFAULT:
                       if (Character.isSpaceChar(source.charAt(i))) {
                           //is not space;
                           return "";
                       }
                       break;
                    case MODO_HEXADECIMAL:
                       if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(source.charAt(i)) && !Character.isSpaceChar(source.charAt(i))) {
                           //is not(Letter or Digit or space);
                           return "";
                       }
                        //Only allow characters "0123456789ABCDEF";
                        Matcher matcher = patern.matcher(String.valueOf(source.charAt(i)));
                        if (!matcher.matches()) {
                            return "";
                        }
                       break;

                }
                //Add character to Strinbuilder
                sb.append(source.charAt(i));
            }

            return  sb.toString().toUpperCase();
        }
    };

    myEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { inputFilterText });
    myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);

  }
```

Comment: Jorgesys, con tu código puedo ingresar los textos libres pero como hago para interactuar entre ambos tipos (hexadecimal y texto libre), yo necesito seleccionar mediante un botón si estoy en modo de texto libre o modo hexadecimal

Comment: @W1ll ok, recuerda que es importante seas especifico cuando preguntes, esto ahora da más información acerca de lo que en realidad deseas.Actualizo mi respuesta.

Comment: He actualizado @W1ll